# Why did Russia target the Czech republic?

Tags: russian-federation, czech-republic

- [Czech Republic–Russia relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_Republic%E2%80%93Russia_relations#2021%E2%80%94present)

> (...) the Czech intelligence agencies had concluded that Russian military intelligence officers, namely members of Russian military intelligence GRU's unit 29155, were involved in two massive ammunition depot explosions in Vrbětice [cs] (part of Vlachovice), near the Czech-Slovak border, in October 2014. (...)

Why did Russia target the Czech republic?

What did Russia achieve by blowing up an ammunition depot?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Vrb%C4%9Btice_ammunition_warehouses_explosions#Involvement_of_Russian_GRU

Comment: Given that Russia denies the allegations, it is unlikely that we can offer an answer that meets the requirements of this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the BBC (https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-56796324)

> Czech media reports, quoting unnamed investigators, suggest arms and ammunition at the depot might have been destined for either Ukrainian forces fighting pro-Russian rebels or rebels in Syria fighting the Russian-backed government there.

Russia has a habit of targeting and intimidating those who oppose it - there have been multiple suspicious deaths of Putin opponents living abroad and clear evidence in the Skripal attack.

The attack might have been directed against specific exports or intended to discourage the Czech Government from allowing such trade in the future.